# What's the difference between TLS and SSL in smtplib Python

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, tls1.2

We have written a program in Python, where we are sending a mail to our private gmail account. We can use either SSL or TLS but we're in doubt in which is the most secure protocol to use.

This is our code:

```
def send_mail(subject, msg):
    try:
#       server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587') # TLS (DOES NOT WORK WITH SSL)
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com:465')
        server.ehlo()
#       server.starttls() #TLS (DOES NOT WORK WITH SSL)
        server.login(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, config.PASSWORD)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, config.SEND_EMAIL, message)
        server.quit()
        print ("Successfully sent email")
    except SMTPException:
        print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

What we want to know is what is the most secure to use for smtp? TLS or SSL?

Comment: Maybe [the stack exchange answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161924/why-does-gmail-add-accounts-using-smtp-server-recommend-ssl-instead-of-tls) could be useful info.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveStSomeWhere. That was very useful!